# Convert a numeric string to number of array keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am getting a random number from user input (lets say `$n`). Is it possible to create numeric array keys `array(1, 2, 3, ....., $n )` up to the number given by the user? Actually I want to use it in a foreach loop and echo the value.

Here is one of the codes I have used.

```
$n = $_GET['num'];
foreach ($n as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
```

How do I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foreach(range(1, $n) as $a) {...}` or `for($a =1; $a <= $n; ++$a) {...}`... the latter doesn't have the overhead of creating an array

Comment: Thanks.. Been pulling my hair out since last couple of hours. You just saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

In `foreach` a temporary memory of variable is created which gets flush after the loop has completed it's execution. Prefer to use `foreach` when you already know that `key | value` relationship exist.
To create an array upto $n, you can use a `for` loop:

```
$array_up_to_n = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
    $array_up_to_n[] = $i;
}
//you can verify it by:
print_r($array_up_to_n);
```

I hope you want this result and I have understood correctly
For Your Information:
whenever you use `foreach` and you want to get result in an array, always declare an array before `foreach` and use it inside like:

```
$my_array = array();
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $my_array[] = $row;
}
```

because `$row`memory gets flushed after this loop

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind destroying `$n` in the process, you can just decrement it:

```
for(;$n;$a[$n--]=1) {}
```

This creates the keys in reverse numeric order of course.  You can always [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) if that's important.

Destroying `$n` may not be much of an issue, because the same value should result from `count($a)` after the for loop finishes.

Comment: Purists may prefer the second option in `for` to be `$n>0` rather than just `$n`, but if you know you're always getting an integer in `$n`, the shorter version should work just fine.